# Routing using ASPNET Core 2.0 RazorPages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I've done quite some ASP.NET API programming over the years, but am very new to .NET Core and RazorPages. I cannot seem to get routing working properly.

For example, I have an Index page. The OnGet works fine, as expected, it returns the Razor defined page. Now I add another method, let's call it Test to the Index page codebehind, like so:

```
[Route("Test")]
public void Test()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test");
}
```

Now for the life of me, I cannot access this route, neither by localhost/Index/Test or localhost/Test or any other convoluted route I can think of. Is this by design? Both localhost and localhost/index return the default get method.

This is causing me quite a bit of trouble where I am trying to display a product's details using the owner and product Id in a pretty URL, like so:

```
products/{ownerid}/{productid}
```

As mentioned above, I cannot map to this custom pretty URL. If I understand correctly, the functions mapping to the {ownerid}/{productid} route should be in the index page codebehind in order to be found, or am I mistaken?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's because you are using Razor Pages, which are a failed attempt at remaking webforms. Use the full MVC suite and you will much better off (Razor pages support only a single Get and a single Post method)

Comment: Also notice that in Razor Pages the Controller word is unknown. The "controller" is the view itself, so if you are using an `IndexController` you are doing something wrong

Comment: The controller part was a typo, I meant Page. I see your point. They talked so much about how it's MVC in the background it never crossed my mind routing may not be supported. Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: FYI Multiple Get and Posts are supported on a single page https://codingblast.com/asp-net-core-razor-pages-handlers/

Comment: Routing is supported in Razor Pages: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/310/routing-in-razor-pages.  And they are not a failed attempt to remake Web Forms. That comment is inaccurate and unhelpful. Razor pages is now recommended instead of MVC, which is why it is the default ASP.NET Core project type in VS 2017.

Comment: If Razor Pages are a remake of anything, it's the old .ashx handler pages -- with lots of new features. WebForms were terrible but MVVM is a legitimate architecture and Razor Pages does a pretty good job of getting it right.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it with [multiple handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio#multiple-handlers-per-page):
in your codebehind:

```
public class FooModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("Returns the page");
    }

    public IActionResult OnGetTest()
    {
        return new OkObjectResult( "Test" );
    }
}
```

You could call Test function with request: 
`GET foo?handler=test`.
Also, you can configure a [page route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/razor-pages-convention-features#configure-a-page-route) to call it with `GET foo/test`. You can do it in *foo.cshtml* file with *@page* directive:

```
@page "{handler?}"
@model FooModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Foo";
}
<h2>Foo</h2>
```

Or you can add route in *Startup.cs*:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
        .AddMvc()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions( options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AddPageRoute( "/foo", "foo/{handler?}" );
        } );
    }
```

Same way you can add a route with parmeters:

```
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute( "/foo", "products/{ownerId}/{productId}" );
```

and in codebehind:

```
public void OnGet( string productId, string ownerId)
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("IDs: {0}, {1}", productId, ownerId );
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Add it to the page directive for at the top of the `.cshtml` page:

```
@page "{ownerid}/{productid}"
```

If they are `int`s then also add that constraint

```
@page "{ownerid:int}/{productid:int?}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you look at page handlers?

You can use something like:

```
<form method="GET">
    <input asp-page-handler="Test"> 
</form>

public IActionResult OnGetTest()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this:

**Products.cshtml**

```
@pages "{ownerId}" // note this part! very important!
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages
@model ProductsModel

@functions {
    public class ProductsModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet(string ownerId) // pass the string
        {
            // your code here
        }
    }
}

<div>...</div>
```

This would then map to `http://localhost/products/{ownerid}`

I hope this gets you going in the right direction with dealing with routes in RazorPages.